# Connecting to a MySQL embedded database from PHP

Tags: php, mysql, myisam

I would like to connect to a MySQL embedded database (MyISAM engine).

As you know MyISAM databases files are located in :

```
C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\data\mydb\
```

And has some files with following suffixes for each Table :

```
TableName.frm (Format File)
TableName.MYD (MyISAM Data)
TableName.MYI (MyISAM Index)
```

**The main question :**

How do i connect to a MyISAM embedded database from PHP ?

**P.S:**

I already using MyISAM database as embedded in Windows applications without using MySQL Server.

Just putting some `DLL` files (like `libmysqld.dll`,...) inside `myApp.exe` and myApp run successfully without MySQL Server.

I think it's clear enough.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Probably suitable for [SU].

Answer (score 1):

As I am aware, the only embedded database which PHP supports is SQLite.

In any other ways of trying to connect to MySQL database (with MyISAM engine) you would need either to expect resource from queries, PHP compatible objects, which non of them is the binary format of MyISAM files.

At least, Embedded databases are widespread in application programming, not so much in web programming.

However, I found something, that converts MyISAM to SQLite http://www.fullconvert.com/MyISAM-to-SQLite/

Managing SQLite with php is simply done by `sqlite_` functions which creates files for db's and tables, execute queries, etc.

Small tutorial: http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/PHP_and_SQLite

PHP SQLite official documentation: http://php.net/manual/en/book.sqlite.php